# i am getting an error while using cv2.absdiff()

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, opencv

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p:\EDUCATION\PROJECTS\POLICE\Updated_scanner.py", line 81, in <module>
    faces,motion=detectfaces(frame_count,gray,first_frame)
  File "p:\EDUCATION\PROJECTS\POLICE\Updated_scanner.py", line 19, in detectfaces
    delta_frame=cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'absdiff'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src1 is not a numerical tuple
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src1'
```

I tried using absdiff but it show this error.

[image: 1]

Comment: [mre] is required. also: [tour], [ask]

Comment: And never post code/errors as images!